# Trying to run a python script with php for mounting a luks drive

Tags: python, php, apache, raspberry-pi, sandbox

i am running an apache webserver with php 7.3 on a Raspberry Pi.

Everything is standard. I have got a simple PHP-Page which just run with:

```
shell_exec("/home/user/mount.py mountdrive");
```

to mount a `luks` drive on the Raspberry.

with:

```
shell_exec("/home/user/mount.py umount");
```

i would like to dismount it.

I give my www-data user for testing with `sudoers` all rights and also a bash for testing.

If i change on the terminal to www-data as user i can run the python script and everything works fine. If i run the PHP-script nothing is happen.
The skript is running and i post the different steps for mounting to a logfile. This works. But nothing else.

And also for example if i just try to get the output from Python `cmd: os.path.ismount("/home/user")`
it says on the terminal as www-data user false and on php script true?
How could this be? Looks like a sandbox???

Can someone help me with this?

Thx a lot.

BR kami

Need help? Try Debug logging and maybe it runs in a "sandbox"

Comment: Did you check the web server error log?

Comment: nothing found there.

Comment: Can i get a better debug anyway?